# Commutators of ${\vec x}\cdot{\vec p}$ and ${\vec L}\cdot{\vec S}$ with components of ${\vec L}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators

The operator ${\vec x}\cdot{\vec p}$ commutes with all components of ${\vec L}$. The physical reason for this, as is often stated, is that the components of ${\vec L}$ are the generators of rotations and ${\vec x}\cdot{\vec p}$, being a dot product of two vector operators, is a scalar under rotation. But the operator ${\vec L}\cdot{\vec S}$, despite being a dot product of two vector operators, does not commute with the components of ${\vec L}$. Why does the argument work for ${\vec x}\cdot{\vec p}$ but not for ${\vec L}\cdot{\vec S}$? I want to understand what am I missing here, physically. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The total angular momentum $\vec{J}=\vec{L}+\vec{S}$ is the generator of rotations and not only the orbital angular momentum $\vec{L}$. With the commutation relations $[L_k,L_\ell]=i \varepsilon_{k \ell m} L_m$, $\, [S_k, S_\ell ]=i \varepsilon_{k\ell m}S_m$ and $[L_k,S_\ell]=0$, the scalar operators $\vec{x}\cdot \vec{p}$ and $\vec{L} \cdot \vec{S}$ both commute with all components of $\vec{J}$. The only difference is, that $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{p}$ commute with the spin operator $\vec{S}$, allowing to write $0=[J_k,\vec{x}\cdot \vec{p}] =[L_k,\vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}]$, which obviously does not work in the case of $\vec{L} \cdot \vec{S}$.

Alternatively one could use a notation with tensor products of operators $\vec{J}= \vec{L}\otimes \mathbf{1} + \mathbf{1} \otimes \vec{S}$, $\, \vec{x} \cdot \vec{p}\otimes  \mathbf{1}$, $L_k \otimes S_k$ to clarify the situation.